# How do I save statuses as codes in db but map them to meaningful words in rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, database, save

I need some help with this, please ...

If I save a transaction status as a code in the db, but I want to translate them to meaningful names how do I do that? Is that even recommended? If no, what would be an alternative to that?

For example:
in the db the statuses are "S", "P", "A"
and in the actual application I'd like to display: "Submitted", "Pending", "Approved" accordingly.

Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Say for example you have a model called `Account` in which you are storing the transaction status in a column called `status` whose value will be ione of the codes that you have mentioned, you can do

```
class Account < ActiveRecord::Base
  TRANSACTION_STATUS = {
    "S" => "Submitted",
    "P" => "Pending",
    "A" => "Approved"
  }

  def status
    TRANSACTION_STATUS[self[:status]]
  end
end
```

By this way, your are overriding the method `status` provided by activerecord on `Account` object.

Depending on how you are going to use the `status` field, you might be required to create proper index on those columns (for ex: if you are going to select accounts with pending transaction, etc)

Answer (score 0):

You could try using the [enum column plugin](http://enum-column.rubyforge.org/) to get this functionality.

Migration to create the table:

```
add_column :accounts, :status, :enum, :limit => [:submitted, :pending, :approved],
      :default => :submitted
```

In the model:

```
validates_columns :status
```

In the controller

```
@account = Account.new # It just works :)
```